# What kind of experiment could be conducted to determine how harmful different kinds of soap are for cleaning floors?

Tags: water, plants, waste-water, greywater

Suppose that you are worried about soap entering the rivers after soapy water goes down the drain. The water from the river might be used to irrigate crops, and then people will eat vegtables grown from soapy water. In the Great Plains of the United States, the [Ogalala aquifer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogallala_Aquifer), and other aquifers would be depleted if only water from wells is used to irrigate corn fields and other food crops.

How would a school aged child do a science Fair project on the affect of soap on plants? Mainly, we are interested in treated sewage water containing soap and treated sewage water not containing soap.

I was thinking that if you live in a house in the suburbs, you could water different patches of a lawn with either soapy water or non-soapy water,  but what are your specific suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier as well as more informative to use small pots of something fast growing. Cress, for example, though with a plant with bigger seeds you could count them and compare germination rates.

The growing conditions would need to be identical but a tray of pots on a windowsill could be turned round daily.

Use commercial or home-made compost (potting soil) as a growth medium. Peat free of course. Ensure water doesn't flow into the tray in such a way that it mixes and soaks into all the pots. Measure the amount of water, soapy or otherwise, so it's the same for each pot. Use a control with tap water.

I'm a (very different sort of) scientist so would want to set up several copies of the experiment, where each copy used the same water mixes.

Thinking about sewage (and treatment) complicates things. Grey water irrigation is used without treatment though not usually for crops.